# How to prevent CSS leaking when I need to add HTML codes from other resource to my page

Tags: javascript, html, css, vuejs2, vuetify.js

**The situation here I have is kind of special:**

---

I am using **Vue.js, Vuetify and OpenLayers** to create an app. which shows useful information about the layers to the user.

In one of my vue component, I want to show the user the **WMSFeatureInfo**. which is actually HTML codes in **String**. (When I query the WMS layer using HTTP GET method, I always get a string back, which contains HTML codes in String)

The way I show the user this HTML String is like this: (I will skip the part how I get the HTML String because it is not related to this question)

```
<v-container
    align-content-center
    v-html="feature.WMSFeatureInfo"
>
</v-container>
```

The problem is, the HTML String contains **also CSS styles in it**, and it leaks out. **So every time after I send HTTP GET Request, get the response of this HTML String and present the information to the user, my whole app's font, table background color, and etc. will be changed** (Obviously the CSS styles in the HTML String are overwriting my own CSS style).

Is there a way that I can put the received HTML codes on my page but ignore the CSS codes in it? Or maybe there is a way that I can make the CSS from vuetify always stronger than other?

To make the question more clear, this is the HTML String I got from the GET request:

```
<html xmlns:esri_wms="http://www.esri.com/wms" xmlns="http://www.esri.com/wms">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></meta>
<style type="text/css">sub{font-family: arial;color: #202020} table, th, td {border:1px solid #e5e5e5;border-collapse:collapse; padding: 3px;font-family: arial;color: #202020;} table { margin-bottom:10px; }  thead { font-weight: bold; }tbody { font-size: 80%; }th, td {valign: top;text-align: left;} thead td, th, .property_name {background-color: #75AE7E;}       </style>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<colgroup>
<col width="30%"/>
<col/>
</colgroup>
<thead>
<tr><td colspan="2">schummerung</td></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="property_name">Stretchedvalue</td>
<td class="property_value">181</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="property_name">PixelValue</td>
<td class="property_value">181</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

So after I add these HTML codes to my `<v-container>` (it's just a `<div>`), my other tables on the page (outside of the div container) will get a green background.

I want the CSS styles of this HTML codes only have an effect inside of the `<div>`, but not effects my other tables and fonts on my page.

Comment: Write that string into an iframe

Comment: @charlietfl I only know how to create an iframe with url, but I will search how to do it with HTML String. Thanks for your advise!

Comment: 2 ways...can use document.write or base64 encode it and use a data url. Both ways easy to research

Comment: @charlietfl I just use the srcdoc attribute of the iframe and put all the HTML codes in. And set the default border to inherit. It looks just same as before and the CSS styles are not leaking anymore, thank you!

Comment: Great... i learned something new from that myself. Never knew you could do that to be honest. Note it appears it isn't supported in IE

Comment: What you are asking about is a long lasting problem for everyone who imports other sources they have no control over. It can be far more difficult when one uses frameworks, too. [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM) was created for this very situation but it's new so browser support may not be what you want and, as always, IE and Edge don't support it at all.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by element styling and css import rules.
Take for instance the `thead` you use in your `style` tag, since the style tag in the imported element has a higher priority over any other styling it will apply over any other styling on the `thead` element.

I think this issue could have been avoided by using classnames to style instead of element styling.
Since the creator of the response did not do this you could parse it to HTML with JS and filter out the style tag. using the DOMParser, and standard DOM element APIs. And after that loop through the `parsedDocument.body` and place the elements in a target element.

I think this should do the trick, unless you want to keep the styles.
In that case you could manually copy the styles and add them to your stylesheet nested under the target element.

```js
// Initiates parser
const parser = new DOMParser();

// Returns Document object (can be used as Document.getElementById('etc'))
let parsedDoc = parser.parseFromString('<html><style>thead{background: #000}</style></html>', 'text/html');

// Gets first style tag
let styleTag = parsedDoc.getElementsByTagName('style')[0];

// Removes first style tag
parsedDoc.head.removeChild(styleTag);

// Removes reference to the style tag
styleTag = null;

// Place each element in the target element
for (let element of parsedDoc.body.children) {
    // document.getElementById('target').appendChild(element);
}
```

If this is not the wanted result, or messy by the project standards, the Iframe will also work.

Answer (score 0):

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
    theme: false
});

Will disable completly the addition of theme style inside the html. This means you won't have colors anymore :
[white on white buttons and white on black icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTCtF.png)

---

To get them to work again - in a more controlled way of course - I took the previously generated css `<head><style id="vuetify-theme-stylesheet">...</style>` to assets/contained-theme.less

`vue-app/
 - node_modules/
 - public/
 - src/
    - assets/
       - contained-theme.less
    - components /
    - App.vue
    - main.js
 - package.json`

My contained-theme looks like :

```
.vuetify-container {
  ...copy the #vuetify-theme-stylesheet css here
}
```

And it has to be imported in your main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';

import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import './assets/contained-theme.less'; // <--------
```

This prevents the css to apply outside from the root component of your application

```
<v-app id="app" class="vuetify-container">
    <HelloWorld/>
</v-app>
```

You might need to add to your webpack build the less-loader package to load the less file :)

[theme colors are back again!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evsrH.png)